# Selection of data analysis methods?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, selectiveinference

Say I want to classify a set of 10000 observations into 5 categories A, b, c, d, e. I have about 500 statistical tests to choose from for categorization but only want to use 3 statistical tests. If I simply pick the ones with the highest Pearson I get 3 tests that classify A C D E well but miss classify B. If I pick tests 1 209 and 225 and do the final classification by hand on the few companies miss classified my Pearson coefficient is much higher than simply picking top three even though test 209 has a bad Pearson score by itself alone.

How do I find the tests 1 209 and 225?

Comment: Your terminology is unclear. I don't understand whether by categorization you mean classification (are true categories known or not?), neither is it clear what tests you use or what you mean by "Pearson" (many things are named after Pearson). You don't explain either why you want three tests. If your final result relies on doing something "by hand", it seems hard to find a formal method to find what you are looking for.

Comment: @Christian Hennig Edited as suggested yes true categories are known all data is historical and with solutions

Comment: It's still unclear what statistical tests you use, why you want just three, and you still don't say what Pearson coefficient you mean exactly. (It may well be that much better classification methods exists than what you do here, but without further detail it's hard to tell.)